# Flutter_Tex doesn't show any Text

Tags: flutter, dart, tex, flutter-tex

I'm trying to make a math quiz game so to show math equations I use [flutter_tex](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) but the only thing that show it my screen is an error and a very thin line here is a picture:
[image: what shows] the code is very simple this is the code:

```
ListView(
  children: [TeXView(
              renderingEngine: TeXViewRenderingEngine.katex(),

              child: TeXViewDocument(
                  r"""<h2>\( \rm\\TeXViewTest\) 1 with ripple</h2>""",
                                ),
                            ),
                          ]
                        )
```

this is the error that I get:

```
E/InputMethodManager(12646): b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=22 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{30d1916 VFEDHVC.. ........ 0,0-848,4}
Reloaded 1 of 680 libraries in 504ms.
D/EGL_emulation(12646): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdce1a0c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xdce0f030)
D/EGL_emulation(12646): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdce1a0c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xdce0f030)
E/eglCodecCommon(12646): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
E/eglCodecCommon(12646): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000088ef
I/dev.qudorat_ap(12646): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 49665(1916KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1998KB/4011KB, paused 5.422ms total 31.072ms
```

I have tried the examples from the [flutter_tex website](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) but it didn't work as well.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you check it :
https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/430

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. i solved added

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

under application tag in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml you can read more on the dev pub [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex).